# Flask SQLAlchemy: AttributeError: User query attribute is None

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm creating a database connection for my Flask REST API.

How I'm not building a normal web site, I'm not using the `SQLAlchemySessionUserDatastore`, instead of it, I'm using `SQLAlchemyUserDatastore`.

The problem is that I'm not able to look for users through `db_user` (i.e. a `SQLAlchemyUserDatastore` object) and when I try to use the `User` class.
The shown error says that the `query` attribute is None.

**Example of finding user:**

```
user = db_user.find_user(username=username, password=password)
# it raises: `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'filter_by'`

user = User.query.filter_by(username=username, password=password).all()
# it raises: `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'filter_by'`

user = User.query.filter(username=username, password=password).all()
# it raises: `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'filter'`
```

When I list the attributes of User, the attribute `query` exists, but it is `None`:

```
 >>> dir(User) 
 [..., 'is_authenticated', 'metadata', 'prepare', 'query', 'query_class', 'roles']

 >>> User.query
 None
```

Would anyone know what may be happening?

I give all code below.

Thank you in advance.

**Code:**

```
from catalog import app
from catalog.database import conn

...

app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = conn
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False

# Create database connection
db_connection = SQLAlchemy(app)

# auto map tables
db_connection.Model = automap_base(db_connection.Model)

# models
class User(db_connection.Model, UserMixin):
    __tablename__ = 'user'

    roles = relationship('Role', secondary='role_user',
                         backref=backref('users', lazy='dynamic', cascade='all'), cascade="all, delete-orphan",
                         passive_deletes=True, single_parent=True)


class Role(db_connection.Model, RoleMixin):
    __tablename__ = 'role'


class RoleUser(db_connection.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'role_user'

# datastore
db_user = SQLAlchemyUserDatastore(db_connection, User, Role)

security = Security(app, db_user)

...

# try to look for users by username and password

user = db_user.find_user(username=username, password=password)
# it raises: `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'filter_by'`

user = User.query.filter_by(username=username, password=password).all()
# it raises: `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'filter_by'`

user = User.query.filter(username=username, password=password).all()
# it raises: `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'filter'`
```